# USB or Folder Locking Program

Tags: javascript, batch-file, vbscript, usb

Multiple people are attempting to steal my data from my USB. I am currently using `Batch` to keep my data safe, however, batch cannot mask "passwords" so therefore my system is useless if anyone is standing behind me.

Furthermore, the problem is harder to solve because my system administrator has banned the use of executables (`.exe` and `.com`).

I am planning on making a new system to lock folders, with `VBScript, JScript, HTML` or with another language which has a reasonable `GUI`.

Most importantly I want the password masked i.e asterix (*******************).

Secondly, I have multiple folders to lock, it would be nice to have something which says `"Open Folder A"` or  `"Lock Folder C"` or `"Lock All Folders"`

If possible, I would like to have a `"Dummy Screen"` which is used when the password is incorrect, saying something like "no data stored", `"System Error 403"` or `"File Corrupt"` when an unauthorized person tries to access the data.

Comment: Use disk encryption like TrueCrypt. You can use a hidden volume for plausible deniability.

Comment: I seriously doubt that your batch "solution" is actually capable of keeping your data safe. If you want to secure data on removable media like USB sticks, BitLocker-To-Go or TrueCrypt are the way to go.